# stop onblur running if textbox is double clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onblur

I have a textbox where the user can enter in an account code. The textbox has an `onblur` function to run some validation on the account code. 
The textbox also has a function for then the user double clicks on the textbox. This opens a screen that shows information on the account code.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAccountCode" CssClass="lookup" MaxLength="8" style="text-transform:uppercase" ondblclick="OpenCust(this.value)" onblur="CheckIfAccountCodeValid(this.value)"></asp:TextBox>
```

The problem is every time the user double clicks on the textbox it also runs the `onblur`. Is there a way to stop running the `onblur` when `ondblclick` is called?

Comment: in your `OpenCust(this.value)` remove `onblur` using `$(this).removeAttr('onblur');`

Comment: this suggestion is wrong. if he removes the onblur attr,  then he will lose the onblur check in the future always

Comment: @quirimmo would there be a way to put back the onblur attr after the ondbclick is run?

Comment: added an answer with a code sample. I think it should make the trick with less changes as possible

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the order that the browser fires events. 
`onblur` is triggered after `onmousedown`, but before `ondblclick`. 
My suggestion in order to keep things easiest as possible is to manage everything inside the `ondblclik`, so something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAccountCode" CssClass="lookup" MaxLength="8" style="text-transform:uppercase" ondblclick="OpenCustIfValid(this.value)"></asp:TextBox> 

function OpenCustIfValid(value) {
    if (CheckIfAccountCodeValid(value)) {
        OpenCust(value);
    } 
}
```

Comment: OP wants to remove blur event and as per your code seems like you're calling the blur event every time user double click on input isn't is wrong ?

Comment: Actually what he wants to achieve is to validate field and open the cust panel only if it is valid

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the onBlur eventlistener in the OpenCust function.

Something like this in Vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById('txtAccountCode').removeEventListener('ondblclick', CheckIfAccountCodeValid);
```

Comment: In this way he will lose the ondblclick in the future after the first onblur will be triggered, and it is triggered always before the dbl click. So this is equivalent to remove the ondblclick attribute directly from the HTML, and this is not what he wants

Comment: @quirimmo Fair point. I figured that the event could be restored once the function had completed but without testing it further I wouldn't want to comment.